# QGIS 3.4 losing edits after saving

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, editing, digitizing

I have constant problems in saving edits in QGIS. I have seen this behaviour with multiple geometry types, namely polygons, multipolygons and points.

Say that I want to update a value in one cell of a point layer (.geojson). I press toggle editing, edit the cell content (using the right type of content), save changes with save layer edits-button and then press the toggle edit button once again to close editing. Then I close the attribute table, and when I open it again the edits have disappeared.

How should I troubleshoot this further? Can this be related to point / polygon type, e.g. multipolygon or multipoint?

I am using 3.4.10 LTR release.

Comment: I guess this issue only appears when you are working with `.geojson`?

Comment: Yes, geopackage seems to be fine

Comment: Well, there's your answer. Though QGIS can read a lot of data types, several of them (`.kml, .dxf, .geojson` e.g.) can not be edited without saving them to `.shp` or `.gpkg`.

Comment: This is a QGIS on Windows bug https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760